# use a customer-encrypted disk in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to use a customer-encrypted disk with a kubernetes pod and I found no documentation about that.

I created customer-encrypted disk, I used it as a volume with my pod and I have this (expected) error message : `AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "eventstore-persistent-storage" : googleapi: Error 400: 'projects/pagaio-177714/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/eventstore-crypt-disk' is protected with a customer supplied encryption key, but none was provided., resourceIsEncryptedWithCustomerEncryptionKey`

unfortunately I sse nothing in the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk) about providing the encryption key.

Is it possible to use something like the [cloud_sql_proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-container-engine) to provide the key and mount the volume ?

If it's not possible to use customer-encrypted disk, do you know some alternative about encrypting an entire volume  ?

Thanks

Comment: did u solve the issue .i AM GETTING SAME for another scenerio

Comment: No I found no solution, sorry.

Comment: I found the solution did u need anymore?

Comment: Yes thank I would like to know how you solved this issue. Thank you.